# Where can I get a short run of standard cards with custom backs?

Tags: playing-cards

I want to print regular playing cards, with backs that I designed. Does anyone know where I could print a deck of cards for a good price with good quality cards? I only want about 50 to 100 decks to start with. Zazzle costs a bit too much for me ($20 a deck), and Bicycle doesn't give a set price.

Comment: possible duplicate of [On-Demand Cards Deck printing service?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/3236/on-demand-cards-deck-printing-service)

Comment: I don't think he ever found good quality card printing.

Comment: what makes you think asking the question again will get different results?

Comment: not a duplicate. on-demand and short-run have some overlap, in that he could just order 50 decks of his own game from an on-demand service, but there are companies out there that do short run printing for less money than an on demand service would charge.

Comment: PS: I just added another answer to @user1873's linked question

Answer (score 1):

Bicycle has a custom card page: http://www.bicyclecards.com/custom, but you must contact them for pricing. They have two tiers *personalized* which is 1-500 decks, or *custom* which is 2500+ decks.

Comment: do you know how much it would approximately cost if i ordered the 2500 decks but used my own designs for just the backs but everything else the same as regular cards? what would be cheapest way?